# Count overlapping intervals by ID BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to count how many overlapping interval I have, according to the ID

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 1001 as id, 1 AS start_time, 10 AS end_time UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 2, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1002, 3, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1003, 5, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1003, 6, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 6, 20 
)
```

[image]

In this case the desired result should be:

```
2 overlapping for ID=1001
1 overlapping for ID=1003
0 overlapping for ID=1002
TOT OVERLAPPING = 3
```

Whenever there is a overlapping (even partial) I need to count it as such.

How can I achieve this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is simple and quite straightforward self-joining and checking and counting overlaps

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.id, 
  COUNTIF(
    a.start_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time
    OR a.end_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time
    OR b.start_time BETWEEN a.start_time AND a.end_time
    OR b.end_time BETWEEN a.start_time AND a.end_time
  ) overlaps
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
ON a.id = b.id AND TO_JSON_STRING(a) < TO_JSON_STRING(b)
GROUP BY id
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - it results with

```
Row id      overlaps     
1   1001    2    
2   1002    0    
3   1003    1
```

Another option (to avoid self-joining in favor of using analytics functions)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id,
  SUM((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM y.arr x
    WHERE y.start_time BETWEEN x.start_time AND x.end_time
    OR y.end_time BETWEEN x.start_time AND x.end_time
    OR x.start_time BETWEEN y.start_time AND y.end_time
    OR x.end_time BETWEEN y.start_time AND y.end_time
  )) overlaps     
FROM (
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(start_time, end_time)) 
      OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TO_JSON_STRING(t) 
        ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
      ) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
) y
GROUP BY id
```

Obviously with same result / output as previous version

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing it now on my real data (about 20GB) but it's taking its time..

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, it works like a charm! I'm a little confused over `TO_JSON_STRING(a) < TO_JSON_STRING(b)`. Is this equivalent to `a.start_time < b.start_time`, or is there something more to it that I don't understand?

Comment: @David - it is similar to a.start_time < b.start_time if there were distinct start times, which I don't know if this is a case in OP's case  - so `TO_JSON_STRING(a) < TO_JSON_STRING(b)` guaranties that two rows will not be joined twice

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: sure, consider voting up the answer if not yet :o)

Answer (score 0):

The logic for *all* overlaps compares the start and end times:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       COUNTIF(t1.end_time > t2.start_time AND t2.start_time < t1.end_time) as num_overlaps
FROM `project.dataset.table` t1 LEFT JOIN
     `project.dataset.table` t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id 
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

That is not exactly what you want, because this compares every interval to every other interval, including itself.  Removing the "same" one basically requires a unique identifier.  We can get this using `row_number()`.

Further, you don't seem to want to count overlaps twice.  So:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by start_time) as seqnum
      from `project.dataset.table` t
     )
SELECT t1.id, 
       COUNTIF(t1.end_time > t2.start_time AND t2.start_time < t1.end_time) as num_overlaps
FROM t t1 LEFT JOIN
     t t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.seqnum < t2.seqnum
GROUP BY t1.id;
```